# Do French users typically use \u00A0 for thousands separator, or normal space, or none at all?

Tags: java, parsing, internationalization

The default thousands separator for Java's Locale.FRANCE DecimalFormat is `\u00A0` (non breaking space).  That's cool for formatting to avoid having numbers break onto separate lines.  But for *parsing* it would depend on whether French users actually enter that character, or a normal space (`\u0020`), or either one depending (like maybe pasting from another source).  Is there any place I can find data on what is actually done by real users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real french users wouldn't type `\u00A0`, because the keyboard doesn't have a character for it. You're confusing presentation with data. You have to validate the user's input, so it'll be easy to disallow any spaces (or use a component that gets rid of the typing completely).

Comment: Yes, it is easy to disallow any spaces.  But is that what a French user expects?  Do they expect to be able to type "123 456" and have it interpreted as a six-digit number?

Comment: @Enwired if you're going to start writing software based on what the user expects, you'll never be finished. Besides, did you even read my answer? Spaces aren't a concern, they're used for display, and if you're thinking "hmm, do the French want to include spaces in numbers?" you're wasting your time.